# datatables warning: table id=laravel datatable -exception message undefined index yajra

Tags: laravel-6, yajra-datatable

good morning, 
I have the following error when inserting data to my datatable.

this is my query from my controller

```
if(request()->ajax()) {

        $user = auth()->id();
        $queja = Queja::join("reportes","reportes.id_reporte","=","quejas.id_reporte")->where('reportes.id','=',$user)->orderBy('reportes.fecha','asc')->get();
        return datatables()->of($queja)
        ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                    $button = '
                        <div class="btn-group text-right">
                                <button type="button"   class="btn btn-success br2 btn-xs fs12 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> OPCIONES
                                    <span class="caret ml5"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a id="'.$data->id_queja.'" href="#">VISUALIZAR</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>';
                    return $button;
                })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->make(true);

    }  
   return view('personal.listar.listar_quejasPersonal');
```

this is my ajax

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
      $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
             processing: true,
             serverSide: true,
             ajax: {
              url: "{{ route('Quejas.Lista.Personal') }}",
              type: 'GET',
             },
             columns: [
                        { data: 'folio', name: 'reportes.folio', width: '10px' },
                        { data: 'asunto', name: 'reportes.asunto' },
                        { data: 'depto_area', name: 'reportes.depto_area' },
                        { data: 'ubicacion', name: 'reportes.ubicacion' },
                        { data: 'nom_trabajador', name: 'quejas.nom_trabajador' },
                        { data: 'fecha_vencimiento', name: 'quejas.fecha_vencimiento' },
                        { data: 'status_queja', name: 'quejas.status_queja', width: '10px' },
                        {data: 'action', name: 'action', width: '10px' , orderable: false}, 

                      ],
            order: [[0, 'desc']]
          });
     /*  When user click add user button */


       /* When click edit user */


       });
```

and this is my .blade

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table admin-form theme-warning tc-checkbox-1 fs13" id="laravel_datatable" width="100%" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-light">
                                <th class="text-center">FOLIO</th>
                                <th class="">ASUNTO</th>
                                <th class="">DEPTO/AREA</th>
                                <th class="">NOM. TRABAJADOR</th>
                                <th class="">UBICACION</th>
                                <th class="">FECHA & HORA</th>
                                <th class="text-right">STATUS</th>
                                <th class="text-right">ACCIONES</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

When I enter a single record, it shows me correctly, but when I have more records, it gives me the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdILr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uai1L.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
       if (!$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#postsTable')) {
              $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
                     processing: true,
                     serverSide: true,
                     ajax: {
                      url: "{{ route('Quejas.Lista.Personal') }}",
                      type: 'GET',
                     },
                     columns: [
                                { data: 'folio', name: 'folio', width: '10px' },
                                { data: 'asunto', name: 'asunto' },
                                { data: 'depto_area', name: 'depto_area' },
                                { data: 'ubicacion', name: 'ubicacion' },
                                { data: 'nom_trabajador', name: 'nom_trabajador' },
                                { data: 'fecha_vencimiento', name: 'fecha_vencimiento' },
                                { data: 'status_queja', name: 'status_queja', width: '10px' },
                                {data: 'action', name: 'action', width: '10px' , orderable: false}, 

                              ],
                    order: [[0, 'desc']]
                  });

        }

       });
```

this error was in name:''

since I had like `{ data: 'asunto', name: 'reportes.asunto' }`, then I changed it for this
`{ data: 'asunto', name: 'asunto' }`,